# Getting error in hibernate annotation class

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-criteria

**I am getting an error in my hibernate programme as I used the
annotation in my bean class and I added the mapping class in the hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: current_leave is not mapped
```

> main class is having files of connection

```
final Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure(HibernateCfgUrls.MYSQL_CFG);
        final StandardServiceRegistryBuilder builder = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                .applySettings(configuration.getProperties());
        final SessionFactory factory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(builder.build());
        final Session session = factory.openSession();
        String hqlQuery = "from current_leave";
        Query query = session.createQuery(hqlQuery);
        List<LeaveStatus> listCategories = query.list();
        for (LeaveStatus list : listCategories) {
            System.out.println("===============");
            System.out.println("Employee id" + list.getStartDate());
            System.out.println("Employee name" + list.getEndDate());
            System.out.println("Employee address" + list.getLeaveName());
            System.out.println("Employee address" + list.getComments());
        }
```

> leaveStatus.java it is the pojo class

```
package com.bizee.bean;

import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.SecondaryTable;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;

@Entity
@Table(name = "current_leave")
public class LeaveStatus 
{
    @Column(name = "start_date", table= "current_leave")
    private Date startDate;
    @Column(name = "end_date", table= "current_leave")
    private Date endDate;
    @Column(name = "comments", table= "current_leave")
    private String comments;
    @Column(name = "leave_id", table= "current_leave")
    private int leaveName;

    public LeaveStatus() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    public LeaveStatus(Date startDate, Date endDate, String comments, int leaveName) {
        super();
        this.startDate = startDate;
        this.endDate = endDate;
        this.comments = comments;
        this.leaveName = leaveName;
    }
    public Date getStartDate() {
        return startDate;
    }
    public void setStartDate(Date startDate) {
        this.startDate = startDate;
    }
    public Date getEndDate() {
        return endDate;
    }
    public void setEndDate(Date endDate) {
        this.endDate = endDate;
    }
    public String getComments() {
        return comments;
    }
    public void setComments(String comments) {
        this.comments = comments;
    }
    public int getLeaveName() {
        return leaveName;
    }
    public void setLeaveName(int leaveName) {
        this.leaveName = leaveName;
    }
}
```

> hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://xxx.xxx.xx.xx:xxxx/abc_hrms</property>
        <property name="connection.username">xxxxx</property>
        <property name="connection.password">xxxxxxxxxxx</property>
        <property name="connection.pool_size">10</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
        <property name="format_sql">true</property>

        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <mapping resource="com/bizee/bean/employeeHBM.xml" />
        <mapping class = "com.bizee.bean.LeaveStatus"/>
        <!-- <mapping  class = "com.bizee.bean.EmployeeDemo"/> -->
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: Inthe hql query Did you try to use the java class (better if full qualified) name and not the table name?

Comment: can u please explain what trying to say..

Comment: as DineshPandian wrote in HQL queries you must use POJO Class names (full qualified is better solution)

Answer (score 2):

Use `from LeaveStatus` instead `from current_leave`

Comment: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: LeaveStatus is not mapped [from LeaveStatus]

Comment: is  `HibernateCfgUrls.MYSQL_CFG' pointing to the correct `hibernate.cfg.xml'?

Comment: yes, i did but getting now a new error, I am posting that.

Comment: still facing the problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [/leaveservice] threw exception [Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.Table.indexes()[Ljavax/persistence/Index;] with root cause
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.Table.indexes()[Ljavax/persistence/Index;
```